# import nltk Not working in Python (nltk and numpy successfully installed, pip working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, nltk

I've been through many versions of this question on here and I still can't find the answer or figure out why `import nltk` won't work in Python. I have Windows 10, I uninstalled and re-downloaded both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python (currently I only have the 64-bit version installed), and this is what my command prompt looks like:

```
(base) C:\Users\Cathryn>py -3.8-32 -m pip install -U nltk
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.8 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (0.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tqdm in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: regex in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (2020.10.15)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: click in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (7.1.2)
Installing collected packages: nltk
  Attempting uninstall: nltk
    Found existing installation: nltk 3.5
    Uninstalling nltk-3.5:
      Successfully uninstalled nltk-3.5
Successfully installed nltk-3.6.1

(base) C:\Users\Cathryn>pip install nltk
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (0.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (2020.10.15)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (4.50.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (7.1.2)

(base) C:\Users\Cathryn>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\cathryn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.19.2)
```

Yet, when I put `import nltk` into the Python IDLE and the Python window that looks like the windows Command Prompt this happens:

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
>>>
```

I followed all the instructions on https://www.nltk.org/install.html other than using the 64-bit version rather than the reccommended 32-bit version. I downloaded [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) like other answers suggested. I genuinely have no idea what is causing the problem and I would appreciate any help at all.

Thanks for reading this far if nothing else.

Comment: In your command line, can you open `python` like `(base) C:\Users\Cathryn> python` and test `import nltk` instead of using Python IDLE?

Comment: @aminrd This happened ```(base) C:\Users\Cathryn>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 00:03:40) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>>```

Comment: If `import nltk` works from python started from the command prompt, then your IDLE is using a different python than the one you used to install nltk.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I only see one type of python in the Programs and Features window, if I uninstall that one and install the other version will I have to re-install everything else?

Comment: Why would you think that the "Programs and Features window" is the definitive source for the installed python versions? From IDLE, type `import sys` then `print(sys.executable)` to see what python IDLE uses. Or from a Command Prompt, enter `py -0` to list the different versions you have.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I'm a beginner with regards to programming, I haven't done any research or learning in a while and I was trying to figure out nltk for a project I'm working so I don't know some basic things yet. `>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\Cathryn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe
>>> ` this is what came up

Comment: So your IDLE is using python 3.9 but you installed nltk on python 3.8. You can try `py -3.9 -m pip install nltk` from a Command Prompt then try importing nltk again from IDLE.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel you're literally a wizard thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So your IDLE is using python 3.9 but you installed nltk on python 3.8.

You can try

```
py -3.9 -m pip install nltk
```

from a Command Prompt then try importing nltk again from IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is probably using the wrong interpreter. It must point to "PathToAnaconda\python.exe" which is the base environment.